# Product of two bijective functions bijective?

Tags: linear-algebra

If U:H->H and V:H->H are bijective functions, is UV also bijective?

I hope someone can help me with this.

Comment: If by product you mean composition, then yes.

Comment: $U(x)=x$ and $V(x)=x$ are bijections of $H=\mathbb{R}$ onto itself but $UV(x)=x^2$ is not injective on all of $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: No sir. I meant exactly the product UV not the composition of functions.

Comment: Thank you @NapD.Lover! :)